# How can I read properties file in java class located in a folder outside workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle, properties-file

I have a properties file located in `C:/codebase/myProject-Authentication/sample.properties`, and my workspace is at `C:/codebase/myProject/com.company.team.website/src/.../AccessCodeServlet.java`.

So, I need to read `sample.properties` from `AccessCodeServlet.java`. `AccessCodeServlet` is a servlet.

If the properties file is in the same folder as `AccessCodeServlet.java`, I can just do this:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample");
```

But how do I do it when properties file is outside workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can add an external folder containing your *sample.properties* to the classpath in eclipse:

- Open Run Configuration
- Select <Your app entry>
- Go to "Classpath" tab
- Select "User entries"
- Click "Advanced" button
- Check "Add external folder"
- Click "OK" button
- Select your external folder with *.properties* file(s)

Viola - now resource bundles are found!

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to a relative path to the workspace before usage?

```
public void MovePropertiesFile()
{   

    InputStream otherStream = null;
    OutputStream workspaceStream = null;

    try{

        File afile =new File("C:\\somwhere\\.....\\properties.properties");
        File bfile =new File("C:\\workspace\\.....\\properties.properties");

        otherStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
        workspaceStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        while ((length = otherStream .read(buffer)) > 0){

            workspaceStream .write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        otherStream .close();
        workspaceStream .close();


    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't move the file to another location Aaron because that's how the folder structure is and I can't alter that.

Comment: Can you copy it's contents? create a tempory file that will be used on the fly

Comment: Aaron, this works! But, in the production setting, I am not sure if this will be a good approach. Because, there will be no workspace there in that setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify absolute path but you shouldn't hard-code it as you correctly surmised.

You should get the base path of the file(s) from a System property which you can access using System.getProperty("basePath") in your code and which should be prepended to your file name to create an absolute path.

While running your application you can specify the path in java command line as follows:

```
java -DbasePath="/a/b/c" ...
```

... signifies the current arguments to your Java command to run your program.